# "Мы озабочены тем, кем станут сегодняшние школьники" - корректно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, сложное-предложение

Корректно ли предложение?

> Мы озабочены тем, кем станут сегодняшние школьники.

Comment: А что конкретно Вас смущает?

Comment: Преподаватель по русскому языку заметила, что "тем, кем" использовать нельзя и снизила за это оценку. Хотелось бы убедиться права она или нет, ну и как бонус оценку исправить, потому что её претензия звучит странно.

Comment: она перестраховалась, потому что снизить за это теоретически можно, на каком-нить ЕГЭ, а оспорить решение тот еще геморрой, так что лучше сразу писать без возможности придраться, если у вас нет иной задачи или это не супер авторский текст, где каждое слово имеет смысл. Так что дело не в ошибке, а в том, к чему при желании можно придраться, и не писать так сразу - проще, чем потом доказать, что не осёл.

Answer (score 1):

"Тем, кем" не нарушает каких-либо формальных правил русского языка.
С точки зрения стилистики - вопрос дискуссионный, но снижать за это оценку я бы не стал.

Поиск на сайте Национального корпуса русского языка позволяет легко найти примеры литературного применения такого сочетания, причем в самые разные временные периоды. Например:

Б. Л. Пастернак. Начало прозы 1936 года (1936):

> Никогда не задумываюсь я над **тем, кем** он мне приходится.

Андрей Волос. Недвижимость (2000) // «Новый Мир», 2001:

> Пустячная оговорка не испортила дела: во всяком случае, я, слушая и
> попутно размышляя над **тем, кем** и что будет сказано у моего
> собственного гроба, в конце концов невольно прослезился…

Геннадий Николаев. Вещие сны тихого психа // «Звезда», 2002:

> Никаких званий, никаких орденов ― все это шелуха по сравнению с **тем, кем**
> был наш Папа и где он теперь…